# plotting two DataFrame columns with different colors in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame in pandas and I'm plotting two columns out in a line graph using `matplotlib`. However, I can't figure out how to change the individual color of each line. I can only change both or none.
Using .plot() I can only change both eg. `c='red'` but I want different colors for each line. 
[image: Screenshot of code and graph]

Comment: Just add color option: `.plot(figsize=(16,6), color=['green', 'brown'])`.

Comment: Thank you! I was rocking my brain for too long over this.

Comment: If it works, the better way to thank the answerer is clicking the accept button in the answer. You can't vote up until you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

To plot 2 columns of dataframe with colors 'green' and 'brown', use the following code:

```
df[['Close 30 Day MA', 'Close']].plot(figsize(16,6), color=['green', 'brown'])
```

Hope it helps.